# Issue With Infinite While Loop in Python 3.1

Tags: python, loops, infinite

I am creating  a travel agent game in Python 3.1. I have reached an error with my while loop. It will constantly repeat the print() response. I know this is because it is true as long as here is a response for people, but I have no clue how to fix it.

```
people = int(input("Will you be travelling by yourself (1), or as a group of 
two (2)?: "))
while people: 
    if people == 1:
        print("\nAh, a holiday for one! How adventurous.")
    elif people == 2:
        print("\nOoh, bringing a friend! Sounds like fun!")
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter either 1 or 2 to determine the number of 
        travellers.")
        people = int(input("Will you be travelling by yourself (1), or as a 
        group of two (2)?: "))
```

Comment: Any reason for the choice of Python 3.1? That's a very old release, and I'd strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent release like 3.5 or 3.6.

Comment: I am using it for a class I'm taking, this is the only version provided/allowed.

Comment: The loop will execute as long as the input isn't zero!

Comment: You can include `break` statements inside the if statements.

Comment: Or remove `else` and unindent everything after that.

Comment: You never break out of the loop, no. The only way out is `0` or entering a string that's not a number.

Comment: I don't think you even want to use `while people` here. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658) for better strategies to handle taking user input.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any issue with the python version regard to you question.The problem is that, loop will run infinitely because there is no condition to exit from the loop.So to exit from the loop after print statement insert `break`  keyword as follows.

```
people = int(input("Will you be travelling by yourself (1), or as a group of two (2)?: "))
while people: 
    if people == 1:
        print("\nAh, a holiday for one! How adventurous.")
        break
    elif people == 2:
        print("\nOoh, bringing a friend! Sounds like fun!")
        break
    else:
        print("\nPlease enter either 1 or 2 to determine the number of travellers.")
        people = int(input("Will you be travelling by yourself (1), or as a group of two (2)?: "))
```